# Added display:inline-block, but my HTML elements are still spilling over into a different line

Tags: html, css, center, inline, display

I would like to keep some DIV elements on the same plane, and so per the advice I got in this forum, I created these elements

```
<div class="profileField">
    Birthday<br> 
    <div class="select"><div class="select-styled">Select Month</div><ul class="select-options"><li rel="">Select Month</li><li rel="1">January</li><li rel="2">February</li>…<li rel="12">December</li></ul></div>
<div class="select"><div class="select-styled">Select Day</div><ul class="select-options"><li rel="">Select Day</li><li rel="1">1</li>…<li rel="30">30</li><li rel="31">31</li></ul></div>
<div class="select"><div class="select-styled">Select Year</div><ul class="select-options"><li rel="">Select Year</li><li rel="1900">1900</li><li rel="1901">1901</li>…<li rel="2020">2020</li><li rel="2021">2021</li></ul></div>
      </div>
```

and here are the styles, which both include “display:inline-block”

```
.select {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 220px;
    height: 42px;
}
.profileField {
        padding: 10px;
        font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 20px;
        display: inline-block; 
}
```

The above sits in a container, with style

```
#profileContainer {
    border-radius: 25px;
    background: #000000;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

but even this has display:inline-blocks o I’m not sure why these elements are going down to new lines.  I crated this JSFiddle to demonstrate the problem — https://jsfiddle.net/4g7r5zt0/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `white-space: nowrap` to this rule, which tells its children to stay on 1 line

```
.profileField {
  padding: 10px;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LGSon/4g7r5zt0/7/)

Comment: Hi, I added this in but this puts everything on the profileContainer on the same line.  I have other <div class="profieField"> elements that I want to remain on their own lines.  I updated my JSFiddle to reflect this.

Comment: @Mike Updated my answer ... same property, another CSS rule